# How to move resources from subscriptions in different directories in Azure

Tags: azure

In my azure account I have 2 directories, lets call them directory A and B.
With some recent changes I need to switch a app service from a subscription in directory A to a subscription that is on directory B.

Is this possible to achieve, and if it is how?

***EDIT 1***

As directory I mean the directory that you can see in the image below:
[image]

***EDIT 2***

Since It seems that I have mislead people I will try to explain what i want to achieve with images.
I want to move the App Service from the App Service Plan in the directory A as you can see in here:
[image]
to the App Service Plan in the directory B that you can see in here:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by directory? do you mean Active Directory Domain or something else?

Comment: @AndySinclair  I updated the question with an image showing what I want to say as directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to move resources between subscriptions. It is possible to do this but there are a few restictions and rules around what you can do.

You can definitely move an App Service between subscriptions. However, in your case, as the subscriptions in question exist in different AD tenants, you will need to change the tenant of one of the subscriptions. You can only do this if you are a Service Administrator and signed in using a Microsoft i.e non organizational account.

Check this [reference document from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources), it explains in detail how the transfer process works.

Comment: After I add myself as owner of the subscription on the directory B I was able to change subscription from directories and after change app service plan from subscriptions. Finding that option to edit directory of the subscription on the old azure portal did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think we might need some additional information, since it seems that the terms we're using are sometimes equivocal. Microsoft Azure subscriptions are not associated to Azure Active Directories, but to an Service Account. You can add how many Azure ADs you want to an Azure subscription, but the Azure subscription itself will be managed by the service account (which is not necessarily member of a certain Azure AD).

Further, only the service administrator can manage Azure resources, like VMs, App Services and so on. Azure AD admins can only manage identity aspects that define identity life cycles within that specific Azure AD. The service admin could add a co-admin a user from the default Azure AD and that user would then also be able to manage Azure resources, like App Services and so on.

So the Azure App Service is tied to a Azure subscription that is managed by a service account, not by the Azure AD. Please check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory) on this topic. Also please clarify exactly what you would like to do.

Comment: Hi @Dan sorry if I was misleading people with my question, I was just asking as I see the information on the portal. I updated the question with an Image, and as you describe it seams to be a service account ant not a directory can you confirm that with the image I upload, and get back to me so I can update the question, with the right information? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so easy to confirm it via the picture you shared, because the service account can be either a Microsoft account (@outlook.com) or an existing Azure AD Account (like john@contoso.com). But just to understand, based on the screenshot you shared, I can see that, let's say, directory A is set as default directory. Would you simply want to add directory B as a default directory instead? The way how the app services works doesn't have anything to do with the directory, because it is associated to the service administrator, not to a specific directory.

Comment: Basically the only difference between the default directory and the other directories is that you can add co-administrators from the default directory. Co-admins can then create Azure resources and so on. You cannot make co-admins user from an Azure AD that is not the default one. But the App Service configuration, billing and so on, will remain exactly the same and nothing would change.