# Move Resource Groups to different azure accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I have two Azure Subscriptions, Enterprise and MSDN subsciptions. I want to transfer a resource group from one subsciption to another.  Already found this method but it requires to change the tenant of one of the subscriptions. [How to move resources from subscriptions in different directories in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984920/how-to-move-resources-from-subscriptions-in-different-directories-in-azure)

These accounts have different active directories (Cannot Change Directory). So essentially the tenantid remains different.

Official Docs also mentions this way https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/

Is there any alternate methods to move the RG?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no alternate method to move the RG. What you can do as a Workaround is to try to download the Automation Script (ARM template) for your Resource Group, delete the RG and deploy the template to your new subscription. But this only works for services that uses the Resource Manager (not Service Manager).

Also this only creates the services / infrastructure but you probably have to redeploy content depeding on which resources you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Someone mentioned this can be done by contacting the support.

Answer (score 0):

I found that its possible in some scenarios to do this by moving the resource group to a new/temporary subscription, and then transferring ownership of that subscription to the desire account. It doesn't matter if the account is on a different domain or not, however not all resource types can be transferred (e.g. Azure role-based access control assignments).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/billing-subscription-transfer?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_SubscriptionManagement